# Max value unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a table as follows. If the max confidenceCode value is unique then return that row otherwise no.

```
 LocationID ConfidenceCode
 017755029   05
 017755029   05
 017755029   01
 018577655   05
 018577655   09
 021886301   10
 021886301   09
 021886301   09
```

Expected Output

```
  LocationID ConfidenceCode
  018577655   09
  021886301   10
```

My SQL as below, it is working, looking for better version

```
 ;WITH CTEConfidenceCode as
 (
 SELECT *, dense_rank() over (partition by  LocationID order by 
 [ConfidenceCode] desc)  as ConfidenceRowNum FROM testTable
 ),
 CTEGroup as 
 (SELECT DUNS1,[ConfidenceCode],count(1) countValue  FROM CTEConfidenceCode
 WHERE ConfidenceRowNum=1
 GROUP BY LocationID,[ConfidenceCode])

 SELECT * FROM CTEGroup WHERE countValue=1
```

Comment: I mean I suppose you could just do a select locationid, max(confidencecode) with a not exists clause? e.g. something like `select locationid, confidencecode from (select locationid, confidencecode = max(confidencecode) from testtable group by locationid) as t where not exists (select 1 from testtable where locationid = t.locationid and confidencecode = t.confidencecode having count(*) > 1);` but I don't know how much better that may or may not perform.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a better explanation of why you want more than one row returned. "If the max confidenceCode value is unique then return that row otherwise no." does not explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . .  If I understand your question correctly:

```
select LocationId, ConfidenceCode
from (select tt.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by  LocationID order by ConfidenceCode desc) as seqnum 
      from testTable tt
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by locationId, ConfidenceCode
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: You beat me to it!
Table alias was missing ;)